# C Debug Print Macros doesn't print

Tags: c, macros

I have this macro and this main function.

```
#define DEBUG_INFO(format, args...)  \
        fprintf(stdout, "%12s: %3d: %s ", __FILE__, __LINE__, green), \
        fprintf(stdout, format, ##args)


int32_t main()
{
    if (server_init())
    {
        DEBUG_INFO("Child process wasnt created");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When my main function started to work. It will work return value of server_init(). I used DEBUG_INFO in server_init(),too. After the macro line. When in server_init(), Macro didn't write anything. But if server_init() returns False value. then Macro of main function will write error. Why doesn't work macro in function.

Comment: You need to flush the output buffer, either with a `\n` or using `fflush`.

Comment: Include a newline at the end of the message string, or force one by adding `putchar('\n')` at the end of the macro (after another comma operator), or … Are you sure it is a good idea to write the debug information to standard output?  It is more conventional to use standard error, and `stderr` is usually not fully buffered (so it is line buffered or unbuffered) and minimizes the risk of messages not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` to disable output buffering on `stdout`, or you can simply output a `\n` to flush the output buffer. The second option is preferable.